# SQL select within inner joins

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

My question is: How to get different values in one sql query? I am trying this:

```
SELECT 
          q.id,
          q.question_title,
          SUM(op.option_value) AS total_votes,
          COUNT(op.option_value) AS number_votes,
          tab.comments 
FROM
          questions_options AS op 
          INNER JOIN questions AS q 
                    ON (q.id = op.q_id) 
          INNER JOIN 
                    (SELECT 
                              SUM(p.unseen) AS comments 
                    FROM
                              questions_options AS p) tab 
                    ON (q.id = tab.q_id) 
WHERE op.option_value > 0 
GROUP BY q.question_title
```

This query is working perfectly, If i remove the middle "INNER JOIN" (i.e shows me the id, question title, sum of total votes rating, and the number of votes....

But I want to show unseen comments also, which is another field in that table and takes "1" for unseen (unread) comment...

So how can I do this by putting unseen comments number....any idea or suggestions...

Comment: you have eliminated the q_id field from your subquery named "tab", so of course you can't join on that field anymore.  You probably want `(select sum(p.unseen), p.q_id from questions_options as p group by q_id) tab`

Comment: hi....yes you are right..it show some result...but 2 for all fields, i want only for those fields which have un-read comments...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Judge Mental is right.

You should SELECT the "q_id" field in your subquery to be able to make an inner join to "tab.q_id".

**-Explanation-**

Your first `INNER JOIN` looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM questions_options AS op INNER JOIN questions AS q ON (q.id = op.q_id)`

..so basically the relation (and join) between your two tables is based on 
`questions.id` and `questions_options.q_id`.

Well, it's the same story for you subquery.

In your subquery you define a SELECT statement FROM "questions_options",
which will only return the columns/fields you put after your SELECT.

`(SELECT SUM(p.unseen) AS comments FROM questions_options AS p) tab`

To be able to use any data from you subquery, you will have to `SELECT` the 
`questions_options.q_id` field and make a join with the `questions.id` field already
in your main query.

`(SELECT p.q_id, SUM(p.unseen) AS comments FROM questions_options AS p) tab
INNER JOIN (...subquery...) ON (q.id = tab.q_id)`

So `tab.q_id` refers to the `p.q_id` you selected in your subquery.

Comment: yes working fine...by selecting q_id field in subquery....and then innerjoin on tab.q_id...thank you joshua. But i didn't understand how this working, can you explain it or edit your question for detail...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I am correct, but I have found something here.
If u read OP's query again and again, U will get to know that there is no need for second inner join.
you can also put `sum(p.unseen) as comments` in first `select` itself as it is also asking from the `questions_options` table on the basis of q.id = tab.q_id`, which by itself comes in the first inner join between`questions`and`questions_options`.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: you are right Abhinav, but for this scenario there is different thing...bcz we put some rating of question in option_value and also put comments value for comments...so thats why it can't perform what you are saying.....